# not being able to get a value from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to loop through a dict and get all values for the key 'PolicyName'. This is my code:

```
if (str(account_id)== "010123456"):
                    client = boto3.client('iam', region_name='us-east-1')
                    roles = client.list_roles()
                    attached_policy_dict = client.list_attached_role_policies(RoleName='sf-someRoleName')
                    attached_policy = json.dumps(attached_policy_dict)
                    for k,v in attached_policy_dict.items():
                        print(['AttachedPolicies']['PolicyName'])
                        # I also tried
                        print['PolicyName']

    attached_policy_dict = {
      "AttachedPolicies": [
        {
          "PolicyName": "sfDenyNetworkActions",
          "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::56012365:policy/sfDenyNetworkActions"
        },
        {
          "PolicyName": "sf-csdc-developer-policy",
          "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::563012454:policy/sf-policyname"
        }
```

This is the error Im getting : {

```
"errorMessage": "list indices must be integers or slices, not str",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      35,
      "lambda_handler",
      "print(['AttachedPolicies']['PolicyName'])"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the value of `"AttachedPolicies"` is actually a list of dicts. Else you wouldn't even be able to have several keys of the same name inside.

Try this instead:

```
for d in attached_policy_dict["AttachedPolicies"]:
    print(d["PolicyName"])
```